# jquery click listener only working on first row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason the code below will only trigger the pop up box for the first delete button selected. all other buttons do nothing. How can I modify it so that this button calls the script no matter which row it is clicked on.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</a>
```

This is my `html`

```
@foreach(Tweet::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get() as $tweet)
                    <tr id="{{$tweet->tweet_id}}">
                        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</a></td>
                        <td id="tweet_text">{{$tweet->tweet_text}}</td>
                        <td id="tweet_user">{{$tweet->screen_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$tweet->name}}</td>
                        <td id="tweet_date">{{$tweet->created_at}}</td>
                    </tr>
@endforeach
```

This is my 'script'

```
<script>
    //When the delete button is clicked open the pop up.
    $('#delete').click(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
        //Get the clicked row
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        //Get the ID of the Tweet - the row id
        var tid = row.attr('id');
        //Get the tweet, user and date
        var tweet = row.find('#tweet_text');
        var user = row.find('#tweet_user');
        var date = row.find('#tweet_date');
        //Display details in the pop up
        $('.modal_tweet_text').text(tweet.text());
        $('.modal_tweet_user').text(user.text());
        $('.modal_tweet_date').text(date.text());
        $('.modal_tweet_id').text("Tweet ID: " + tid);
        //Confirm Action 
        $('#confirm_btn').click(function(){
            row.remove();//remove the row
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');//Hide the popup
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: __IDs must be unique__

Comment: Don't think it's fair this question got downvoted, I provided all the information and had a large amount of code.

Comment: I had the same issue so I upvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use same id for multiple button, so change it to class

```
<a class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</a>
```

and bind click event using class selector

```
$('a.delete').click(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
        //Get the clicked row
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        //Get the ID of the Tweet - the row id
        var tid = row.attr('id');
        //Get the tweet, user and date
        var tweet = row.find('#tweet_text');
        var user = row.find('#tweet_user');
        var date = row.find('#tweet_date');
        //Display details in the pop up
        $('.modal_tweet_text').text(tweet.text());
        $('.modal_tweet_user').text(user.text());
        $('.modal_tweet_date').text(date.text());
        $('.modal_tweet_id').text("Tweet ID: " + tid);
        //Confirm Action 
        $('#confirm_btn').click(function(){
            row.remove();//remove the row
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');//Hide the popup
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation, button is no longer there, once you delete it.

```
$(document).on('click','#delete',function(){
```